# ASP.NET MVC4 won't submit with client side validation if first submitted with errors

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple setup but cannot figure out why this wont work. Here's what I have set up:

- MVC4
- Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript() and
  Html.EnableClientValidation() enabled
- jQuery 1.6.2,
  jquery.validate.min.js, and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
  referenced
- No events bound to form or button submit

The problem is, it seems to work on the client side, where I can submit a form and it shows the appropriate validation errors. However, when I then properly fill out the form and hit submit, it does nothing and the last error message I had previously is still displayed. If I go back and clear fields, the validation appears to still be working (validation summary is updated appropriately). If I submit the first time with all fields correctly entered, it works just fine. It's only if I first have an error that it cannot submit again.

The model only has [Required] on firstname, lastname, and email. No other attributes. Also, FormFieldFor is just a wrapper for EditorFor().

Code below. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
@model AscendOne.CareOne.Mvc.Models.ResourceGuideUserModel

@*Form*@
<form id="guide-download-submit" method="get" action="/leads/" target="_blank">

    @{
        Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript();   
        Html.EnableClientValidation();
    }


    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    @if (Model.CampaignID != null)
    {<input type="hidden" name="CampaignID" value="@Model.CampaignID" />}
    @if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.PDFUrl))
    {<input type="hidden" name="RedirectUrl" value="@Model.PDFUrl" />}

    <fieldset>
        @Html.FormFieldFor(m => m.FirstName)
        @Html.FormFieldFor(m => m.LastName)
        @Html.FormFieldFor(m => m.Email)
    </fieldset>

    <button type="submit">Download The Guide</button>

</form>




public class ResourceGuideUserModel
    {
        public string CampaignID { get; set; }
        public string PDFUrl { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("First Name:*")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Last Name:*")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Email Address:*")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Do you get exactly the same results regardless of which fields are filled in or left blank?

Comment: I added the model. I get the same results no matter which order I fill them out. It still shows the last validation message I had before entering all fields correctly. It's as if it's just returning false when I submit.

Comment: The form attributes action and target look suspicious to me. Are they both correct/necessary?

Comment: @Nick - The user is supposed to submit the form and they're taken to a PDF. It opens in a new window and the /leads/ controller is a GET request.

Comment: Perhaps this has changed since MVC3, but it used to be that the validation summary defaulted to NOT showing individual field errors unless you passed `false` into the method.  Does `@Html.ValidationSummary()` still take a parameter?

Comment: Why are you using a manually created form element?  Why not use BeginForm?  What does your action method look like that you are submitting to?  Have you used an Http logger like Fiddler to see if the request is being submitted to the server?

Comment: I'm using Firebug and there is no request/XHR activity at all. It's as if it killed the form. I'm using a custom form because, I have a /leads/ url that captures form input and then redirects the user to a PDF. That part is fine, but since it's not even firing off the form submit at all, I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Hidden fields can be a culprit sometimes in this situation, make sure that you give them enough attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out it was my fault. Thanks for the replies. Seems another deeply-buried script was killing my form submit after the 1st try. Removing this resolved the issue. Thanks again though.